# Reveal modal positioned wrong when using jQuery Isotope

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-isotope, zurb-foundation

I have this issue on a couple of projects, both times using jQuery Isotope in conjunction with Zurb Foundation, and specifically the Reveal plugin for displaying a modal.

http://www.budeblog.com

In the Videos launched in a modal appear to have incorrect z-index, and be positioned somehow relative to their parent container, rather than being presented in the center of a full screen overlay, as would be the expected behaviour. Also, some of the subsequent items are still shown, on top of the overlay. The overlay was working normally until Isotope was introduced.

I've added 'animationEngine: jQuery' to make sure CSS transitions are not used.

Stumped at this point. Any ideas welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never did get Reveal.js to work but seemingly using Fancybox as the overlay in combination with the Recommended CSS at the bottom of http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html seems to be working ok.

Also Fancybox stops the video (I need to output Vimeo embeds via WordPress) automatically on close of the overlay, which Reveal required an extra function for, so a better solution in both respects.